# I try to use emailjs, but I have this error "user id is required". How to fix it?

Tags: javascript

This is the my file index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Contact Form</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/emailjs-com@2/dist/email.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
      (function() {
        emailjs.init("here I put my user Id");
      })();
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('contact-form').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      // generate a five digit number for the contact_number variable
      this.contact_number.value = Math.random() * 100000 | 0;
      // these IDs from the previous steps
      emailjs.sendForm('contact_service', 'contact_form', this)
        .then(function() {
          console.log('SUCCESS!');
        }, function(error) {
          console.log('FAILED...', error);
        });
    });
  }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="contact-form">
    <input type="hidden" name="contact_number">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="user_name">
    <label>Email</label>
    <input type="email" name="user_email">
    <label>Message</label>
    <textarea name="message"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
  </form>
 
</body>

</html>
```

the error message is this:

**{status: 400, text: "The user ID is required. To find this ID, visit [https://dashboard.emailjs.com/admin/integration"}](https://dashboard.emailjs.com/admin/integration%22%7D)**

I created Email Services, Email Templates.
I verified my user id many times on (https://dashboard.emailjs.com/admin/integration).

Comment: `emailjs.sendForm(serviceID, templateID, templateParams, userID)`. This seems to be the syntax. You are not passing the 3rd and 4th params correctly.

Answer (score 7):

EmailJS team has rearranged the dashboard design. "Integration" page has been removed from the dashboard. API keys moved to the "Account" page.
**"User ID" renamed to "Public Key"**

Answer (score 0):

I put js code in main.js in this way

```
emailjs.init("my_user_id");
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('contact-form').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    emailjs.sendForm('my_serves_id', 'my_template_id', this)
      .then(function() {
        console.log('SUCCESS!');
      }, function(error) {
        console.log('FAILED...', error);
      });
  });
}
```

And now all work.

Answer (score -2):

"**User ID**" renamed to "**Public Key**".And it is in **Account Page** of EmailJs

Comment: This answer was already given. Please delete yours.